# Sweeter than honey, hotter than the Sun

Tags: riddle

> It is sweeter than honey.
>   It is hotter than the sun.
>   The King needs it,
>   But a beggar has it.
>   Whoever eats it, dies.

Someone sent me this on WhatsApp. I admit I wasn't able to figure it out. It was originally in a different language, so it may not rhyme.

Comment: Yeah but not exactly. I didn't see that first sorry by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is:

> Nothing. Nothing is sweeter than honey or hotter than the sun. The King needs nothing, the beggar has nothing. Eat nothing and you die of starvation.

Comment: Very Nice answer sir !

Answer (score 0):

By reading Jafe's suggested  question .

> Something also fits. Something is sweeter than honey that could be someone's voice. Something is hotter then sun. Many stars are brighter then our sun. King want something. Read history most of the kings wanted to expand there empire. Beggar has something . Sure he has , he doesn't literally has nothing. Eat something you die that may be poison.